# Iterating over tree nodes in MVC razor view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, tree

Is there any way to code walking the nodes of an a cyclic directed graph?

I'm a little new to ASP.NET MVC and the mode I'm in is trying to render the data in the view model using a contained snippet of logic.

That is to say, if there's no non recursive way to do this then what's the best way to do it recursively "MVC style"?

Here's what I've got so far.

**Model:**

```
namespace AaronWeb.Models
{
    public class Node
    {
        public Node()
        {
            Nodes = new List<Node>();
            Data = string.Empty;
        }

        public ICollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

        public string Data { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            if (Data != null)
            {
                return Data.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model AaronWeb.Models.Node

@{
    var q = new Queue<AaronWeb.Models.Node>();
    q.Enqueue(Model);
}
<h1>Graph Partial View</h1>

@while (q.Count > 0)
{
    var node = q.Dequeue();
    <ul>
        <li>@node.ToString()
            @if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var child in node.Nodes)
                    {
                        <li>
                            @child.ToString()
                        </li>
                        q.Enqueue(child);
                    }
                </ul>
            }
        </li>
    </ul>
}
```

**Action Method**

```
public ActionResult Graph()
{
    var model = new Node
    {
        Data = "Foo",
        Nodes = new[] {
             new Node
             {
                 Data = "Bar",
                 Nodes = new [] {
                     new Node
                     {
                         Data = "Bing"
                     },
                     new Node
                     {
                         Data = "Bang"
                     }
                 }
             },
             new Node
             {
                 Data = "Bat"
             },
         },
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

**Result (Wrong)**

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Graph</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

<h1>Graph Partial View</h1>

    <ul>
        <li>Foo
                <ul>
                        <li>
                            Bar
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Bat
                        </li>
                </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Bar
                <ul>
                        <li>
                            Bing
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Bang
                        </li>
                </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Bat
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Bing
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Bang
        </li>
    </ul>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You say your result is wrong. What is wrong?

Comment: i added a screen shot to make it clearer - there's only one root of my graph but my `<ul>` has multiple roots.. i feel like i'm missing something simple, i know

Answer (score 10):

I figured this out myself.

The key was to realize I could call a partial view recursively!

```
@model AaronWeb.Models.Node
<ul>
    <li>@Model.ToString()
        @foreach (var child in Model.Nodes)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("_GraphPartial", child);
        }
    </li>
</ul>
```